# How to repo init a local .git and local manifest.xml

Tags: git, github, repo

In traditional method, I will use this command to repo init and repo sync, and it works.

```
repo init -u https://github.com/abc/def.git -b main -m manifest.xml
```

But due to some reasons, I need to do something like this：

Step 1: clone the repo to my computer

```
git clone https://github.com/abc/def.git
```

Step 2: repo init from a local .git and local manifest.xml  (Fail)

```
repo init -m manifest.xml
```

Fail at step 2 with this message "fatal: manifest url (-u) is required."

It was inside the git clone directory.

Anyone know how to repo init from a local git repo and local manifest.xml file ? Please provide code example if possible, Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have several options.

If there is already a repo workspace, which means `repo init` has been run and `.repo` exists, you could copy the manifest to `.repo/manifests`. Suppose it's `.repo/manifests/manifest.xml`, or rename it as `.repo/manifests/my_manifest.xml` in order to avoid naming conflicts. And then run

```
repo sync -m my_manifest.xml
```

or

```
repo init -u https://github.com/abc/def.git -b main -m my_manifest.xml
# my_manifest.xml does not have to be tracked as
# long as it's under .repo/manifests
repo sync
```

If your own `manifest.xml` is tracked in a local repository `/path/to/manifests/`, on the branch `foo`, you could also use

```
repo init -u file:///path/to/manifests -b foo -m manifest.xml
repo sync
```

`file://` can be omitted.

BTW, the `remote` element in the manifest file could also be a local repository.

Comment: I am using this repo init -u file:///home/you/my/ -b foo -m manifest.xml
And this error occur:
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/main

Comment: @AnsonTan Did you specify `-b main`? If so, `/home/you/my/` should already have the `main` branch.

Comment: yes, i put a '-b main', then show "couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/main"
What does it mean ?

Comment: @AnsonTan It means that there is no branch named `main` in the local repository `/home/you/my`.

Comment: I only have main branch in https://github.com/abc/def.git, then I git clone it.
How to know which branch I have in the local repository ?
Sorry, I am new to this

Comment: @AnsonTan In the local repository run `git branch` or `git for-each-ref refs/heads`.

Comment: yes, you are correct!! it works after I call "git checkout -b main"

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Local Manifests feature of the `repo` where you can append additional projects.

https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md#Local-Manifests

Init like you normally would

```bash
repo init -u https://github.com/abc/def.git -b main -m manifest.xml
```

Create/copy your custom manifest

```bash
cp my_manifest.xml .repo/local_manifests/
```

Sync

```bash
repo sync
```